# Dialog on time picker

Tags: android, dialog, timepicker

I need some help regarding to the dialog on time picker. Here are the codes

```
static final int dialog_id = 0;
int hour,minute;
Button date;
Button time;
DatePicker dp;
TimePicker tp;
EditText et;
EditText et1;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    date = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    time = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
    showDialog(dialog_id);
}

    protected Dialog onCreateDialogDialog(int id)
    {
        switch(id)
        {
            case dialog_id:
            return new TimePickerDialog(this, mTimeSetListener, hour, minute, false);
        }
        return null;
    }

    et.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            date();

        }
    });

    et1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener=
            new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                @Override

                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
                     hour = selectedHour;
                     minute = selectedMinute;
                    et1.setText( hour + ":" + minute);
                }
            };


        }
    });
```

There is an error in the return new in creating dialog for timepicker the mTimeSetListener.
This is come from a tutorial but it sends me an error..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `mTimeSetListener` should be outside the `onClickListener` or else it won't be visible to the `TimePickerDialog`

Comment: in that case sir.. how can i show the timepicker dialog in onclicklistener sir?

Comment: How are you showing it currently?By calling `showDialog(dialog_id)?`

Comment: Yes but `showDialog` and `onCreateDialog` are deprecated so you should avoid using them. If you have just one `Dialog` that you want to show move the dialog creation code to your `onClickListener`

Comment: `new TimePickerDialog(this, mTimeSetListener, hour, minute, false).show();`

Comment: Use `YourActivityName.this` in place of `this`

Answer (score 0):

Put mTimeSetListener outside the onClickListener because of visibility to the TimePickerDialog and remember to post error details in full next time...